# TCP IP server client delphi when running client abstract error

Tags: delphi, tcp, client, server

Hi I am trying to build tcp server client application in Delphi
I have this code

```
unit UnitClientServer;

interface

uses
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPClient, IdContext,
  SysUtils, Classes, Forms, StdCtrls, Controls, System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList;

type
  TMyPushClientThread = class(TThread)
  private
    TCPClient: TIdTCPClient;
    FLog: TStrings;
  public
    constructor Create(AHost: string; APort: Word; ALog: TStrings);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  TMyPushServer = class (TIdCustomTCPServer)
  protected
    function DoExecute(AContext: TIdContext): Boolean; override;
  end;

  TServerPushExampleForm = class(TForm)
    MemoLog: TMemo;

    aclMain: TActionList;
    Button1: TButton;
    actStartClient: TAction;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure actStartClientExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    ExampleClient: TMyPushClientThread;
    ExampleServer: TMyPushServer;
  end;

var
  ServerPushExampleForm: TServerPushExampleForm;

implementation

uses
  IdGlobal;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TServerPushExampleForm.actStartClientExecute(Sender: TObject);
//var MyClient : TMyPushClientThread;
var myTstring : TStrings;

begin
     FreeAndNil(ExampleClient);
     myTstring := TStrings.Create;
     myTstring.Add('My log');


     ExampleClient:= TMyPushClientThread.Create('localhost', 8088, myTstring)  ;
   //  MyClient.Execute;
end;

procedure TServerPushExampleForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var myTstring : TStrings;
begin
      FreeAndNil(ExampleClient);
     myTstring := TStrings.Create;
     myTstring.Add('My log stevilka 1');
     ExampleClient := TMyPushClientThread.Create('localhost', 8088,myTstring );
end;

procedure TServerPushExampleForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject;
  var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
     // MainWindow.actServer.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TServerPushExampleForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExampleServer := TMyPushServer.Create;
  ExampleServer.DefaultPort := 8088;
  ExampleServer.Active := True;

  ExampleClient := TMyPushClientThread.Create('localhost', 8088, MemoLog.Lines);
end;

procedure TServerPushExampleForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExampleServer.Free;
  ExampleClient.Terminate;
  ExampleClient.WaitFor;
  ExampleClient.Free;
end;

{ TMyPushServer }

function TMyPushServer.DoExecute(AContext: TIdContext): Boolean;
begin
  Result := inherited;

  // simulate hard work
  Sleep(Random(3000));

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(
    'Completed at ' + TimeToStr(Now), TIdTextEncoding.UTF8 );
end;

{ TMyPushClientThread }

constructor TMyPushClientThread.Create(AHost: string; APort: Word; ALog: TStrings);
begin
  inherited Create(False);

  FLog := ALog;

  TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  TCPClient.Host := AHost;
  TCPClient.Port := APort;
  TCPClient.ReadTimeout := 500;
end;

destructor TMyPushClientThread.Destroy;
begin
  TCPClient.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyPushClientThread.Execute;
var
  S: string;
begin
  TCPClient.Connect;

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    S := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(TIdTextEncoding.UTF8 );

    if not TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedout then
    begin
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          FLog.Append(S);
        end);
    end;

  end;

  TCPClient.Disconnect;
end;

end.
```

When I call this button function :

```
 procedure TServerPushExampleForm.actStartClientExecute(Sender: TObject);
//var MyClient : TMyPushClientThread;
var myTstring : TStrings;

begin
     FreeAndNil(ExampleClient);
     myTstring := TStrings.Create;
     myTstring.Add('My log');


     ExampleClient:= TMyPushClientThread.Create('localhost', 8088, myTstring)  ;
   //  MyClient.Execute;
end;
```

I get error Abstract error.
why I can't run the client what is the problem?
I found this code in this post [How to continuously send messages with TIdTCPServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581171/how-to-continuously-send-messages-with-tidtcpserver)

Answer (score 4):

`TStrings` is an abstract class. Using abstract classes produces compiler warnings and runtime errors. You need to use a concrete descendant instead, such as `TStringList`, e.g.:

```
myTstring := TStringList.Create;
```

Comment: I change the code with this line but I did't get the message on the server

Comment: @TOndrej: I wish Delphi would fail at compile time when trying to instantiate an abstract class, like C++ does.

Comment: @ververicka: Then you obviously still have a logic error somewhere in your code.  You need to debug it. If you still need help, post a new question about it.  This question has been answered.